# How can we get user to input values without using a required positional argument when calling a function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter notebook and executing this code:

```
def Power(Number,Index):
    while True:
        Base=int(input(Number))
        Power=int(input(Index))
        data= Base**Power
    return data
```

To call the function Power, I write the following:
    Power(0,0)

[In the Jupyter notebook, when the above is hit shift+enter, user is prompted to enter values. Click this to see details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4egwS.jpg)

However, I want the user to be prompted words (like Number/Base & Power/Index) instead of some random numbers. The user is already going to enter the numbers whose power needs to be calculated.

Ps: Please do not downvote the question I may be banned. This may seem like not a quality question since you are a seasoned professional. But new learners have such weird simple questions.

Comment: THIS IS RESOLVED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the text instead of "0"

call the function as:

```
Power("Enter Number", "Enter Power")
```

Comment: how did you use it, can you print whole thing and do you get any error, do you also realise that you are entering into infinite loop!

Comment: why are you putting "?" at the end of call, thats not required

Comment: Oh damn ! Got it. Thanks. I was trying this without the quotes earlier. In hindsight this seems very silly.